# Convert from SRS coordinates to Latitude and Longitude in Python

Tags: python, coordinates, latitude-longitude, geospatial, epsg

I have a pair of coordinates in SRS (Spatial Reference System):

> EPSG:25830

and

> X: 501343.42
>   Y: 4137351.57

And I want to convert it to Latitude and Longitude.

May be?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What did you try? Are you stuck in any particular step?

Comment: I need convert to Latitude and Longitude Coords. I don't know how i must do it. I dont know if exist a method or direct method to convert it into Latitude and Longitude

Comment: A good start would be looking up `EPSG` on google and finding [the EPSG Registry](http://www.epsg-registry.org/). From there, there are links to a developer guide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SRS is ETRS89 / UTM zone 30N (see http://epsg.io/25830) used in Europe. Within that coordinate system, X **IS** your Longitude and Y **IS** your Latitude. What I suspect you are asking is to reproject those points it into degrees, possibly using the widely common WGS84 coordinate system. If so, there are many ways, for example the command line from the [PROJ4 library](http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/) (which forms the basis for many open source tools)

```
echo 501343.42 4137351.57  | cs2cs -f "%.6f" +init=epsg:25830 +to +init=epsg:4326 

> -2.984825 37.382912 0.000000
```

(see http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/wiki/man_cs2cs)